# QModelIndex as parent?

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt, `QModelIndex` is used to represent an index to my understanding. [Officially](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#details):

> This class is used as an index into item models derived from
>   `QAbstractItemModel`. The index is used by item views, delegates, and
>   selection models to locate an item in the model.

But I see it being used to represent a parent object. For instance, if I want to get an index in a `QFileSystemModel` object, I need a row, column and a parent:

```
QModelIndex QFileSystemModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const
```

I am trying to get a `QModelIndex` object, but to do that, I need another `QModelIndex` object? I am merely trying to iterate over the model. I don't have a separate `parent` object. How do I just create an index from row/column number? I don't understand the role of `QModelIndex` as a "parent". Shouldn't the model itself know what the parent object is? We passed a pointer to the constructor when creating the model.

Here's a bit of code showing the problem:

```
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QDebug>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  auto* model = new QFileSystemModel{ui->listView};
  ui->listView->setModel(model);
  ui->listView->setRootIndex(model->setRootPath("C:\\Program Files"));
  connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this] {
    auto* model = static_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(ui->listView->model());
    int row_count = model->rowCount();
    for (int i = 0; i != row_count; ++i) {
      qDebug() << model->fileName(model->index(i, 0)) << '\n';
    }
  });
}
```

Here I have a `QListView` object (`*listView`) and a `QFileSystemModel`  object (`*model`). I would like to iterate over the model and do something, like print the names of the files. The output is

```
C:
```

No matter which directory the rootpath is. I assume that is because I did't pass anything as the parent.

Comment: you should show your code that isnt working. The declaration you show instead has a default parameter for `parent`, thus it is not clear what is the problem, if you dont know what to pass as `parent` then probably the solution is to not pass anything...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 sure

Comment: see for example the doc for the `parent()` method on the link you posted: "Returns the parent of the model index, or QModelIndex() if it has no parent.". It seems like a `QMOdelIndex` does not need a `parent`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 see the edit for code example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just accessing the children of the root of the `QFileSystemModel` when you default the parent node to `QModelIndex()` in the call `model->index(i, 0)`.

If you also want to list the children of those items, we'll want to iterate them, too:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileSystemModel>

void list_files(const QFileSystemModel *model, QModelIndex ix = {},
                QString indent = {})
{
    auto const row_count = model->rowCount(ix);
    for (int i = 0;  i < row_count;  ++i) {
        auto const child = model->index(i, 0, ix);
        qDebug() << qPrintable(indent) << model->fileName(child);
        list_files(model, child, indent + " ");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QFileSystemModel model;
    model.setRootPath(".");

    list_files(&model);
}
```

See how we pass the child index as the new parent when we recurse into `list_files()`?

Note that the model is likely incomplete at this stage, as it implements lazy reading - so don't expect to see all your files with this simple program.

Comment: Awesome! But what exactly are the children of `QFileSystemModel`?

Comment: `child` is a `QModelIndex`, too.